# Compare two strings in javascript; ASP. NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

On the asp page i have created this function to check if two strings are equal:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
             function ButtonClick(a, b)
{
  if (a == b) 
  {
     alert("Correct!");
  }
  else
  {
     alert("Wrong!");
  }

}
               </script>
```

Then, i have created this function which I use when the page loads, to display everything:

```
public void FillPageSpelling()
    {
        ArrayList videoList1 = new ArrayList();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            videoList1 = ConnectionClass.GetSpelling(1);
        }
        else
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            videoList1 = ConnectionClass.GetSpelling(i);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Spelling sp in videoList1)
        {

            sb.Append(
           string.Format(
               @"<table class='VideoTable'>

<tr>
                <td align='center'><font face='Verdana'> <font size='3'>Level:</font> <font size='2'>{3}</font></font></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>

                <td align='center'><font face='Verdana'> <font size='3'>Sentence:</font> <font size='2'>{1}</font></font></td>
            </tr>


                <tr>
               <td align='center'><font size='3'>Sound:<audio controls><source src=sound/{2}></audio>
                <font face='Verdana'> <font size='2'> </font> </font></td>

                                 </tr>


<tr>



<tr><td align='center'><font face='Verdana'> <font size='3'>Write the word here: <input type=text name=TextBox1></font></font> </td> </tr>    

<td><button name=btnCheck type=button onclick='ButtonClick(TextBox1.Text, lblWord.Text)'>Check</button>  </td> 
<td><button name=btnCheat type=button onclick='ButtonClick(TextBox1.Text, lblWord.Text)'>Cheat</button>  </td>

</tr>

            <tr>



               <td align='center'><font face='Verdana'> <font size='3'>Word:</font> <font size='2'><asp:Label ID=lblWord runat=server>{4}</asp:Label></font></font></td>


                                 </tr>


</br>


           </table>", sp.SID, sp.Sentence, sp.Sound, sp.Level, sp.Word));
            lblOutput.Text = sb.ToString();



        }
```

Well, it turns out I have made a mistake here: `<td><button name=btnCheck type=button onclick='ButtonClick(TextBox1.Text, lblWord.Text)'>Check</button>  </td>`

I changed label lblWord to be a textbox - TextBox2 instead, and this is how you should call the function:

```
<input type=button value='Check' class='p-userButton' onClick='ButtonClick(document.getElementById(""TextBox1"").value, document.getElementById(""TextBox2"").value);'/>
```

Comment: I think you need another closing brace on the function.

Comment: @PollyShaw good eye! i fixed it, but it still doesn't work..

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? You haven't supplied anything resembling a problem statement. What does your javascript have to do with the code-behind method?

Comment: @NicholasCarey, I want to use the javascript function to check if the text written in the TextBox1 is equal to the text of the lblWord

Comment: @NicholasCarey <button name=btnCheck type=button onclick='ButtonClick(TextBox1.Text, lblWord.Text)'>Check</button>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript functions do not have typed parameters. Try your function like this:

```
function ButtonClick(a, b)
{
  if (a == b) 
  {
     alert("Correct!");
  }
  else
  {
     alert("Wrong!");
  }

}
```

Comment: To make sure its always a string comparison, maybe a.toString() == b.toString()

Comment: +1. Note that `===` is better when type is expected to match too.

Comment: Thank you @Yuriy Galanter, but now every time I click the button it says correct, even if it is not...

Answer (score 0):

> function ButtonClick(string a, string b)

javascript does not support parameters with data type:

try : function ButtonClick(a, b)